# Inserting shapefile in AutoCAD Workspace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, autocad

How can I insert an ArcMap shapefile in AutoCad or how can I save the shapefile so as to put it in Autocad Workspace? Even a tool in ArcMap that exports shapefile in a form which can be inserted in AutoCad or AutoCad Map would do.

Comment: Both ArcMap and ArcCatalog has a command button in their toolbar with red icode named ArcToolBox. Try ArcToolbox/Conversion Tools/To CAD/Export toCad.It converts you shape file into a CAD drawing.

Comment: It was a little helpful but I had to use feature to line first and then export to Cad.

Comment: There is also a tool from ESRI for AutoCAD that imports ArcGIS files without converting. I don't remember the name but you can google that.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the dxf interchange format for CAD to export your data. This conversion tool is available in ArcMap (Conversion toolbox/to cad/ export to cad, then choose dxf as output format).

from the other side, shapefiles can be imported in AutoCAD MAP 3D using insert > import panel > map import

Comment: Couldn't find "the dxf interchange format for CAD" in Conversion Toolbox. 

In which workspace of autodesk exactly? There is no "import panel" option in "insert" menu neither in Autocad nor Autocad Map.

Comment: In the search menu in arcmap type "dwg" or "dxf".  side note... if you are  having trouble with this part:   think about  this before you export gcs data to dwg.  autocad handles coordinates very differently than armap.  Depending on what your doing you may need to scale on the backend.  You can quickly butcher your data if you blindly use autocad or esri tools.